# "Wig one," "wig two," "wig three," and "wig four"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "wig one," "wig two," "wig three," and "wig four" in the following sentences?

> A big box sat upon a mat. Can Dog win the big box? Dog got the box!
>   Fox got wig one. Ox got wig two. Cat got wig three. Dot got wig four.
>   Don got wig five. What a lot in a big box!

Does it mean "Fox got one wig. Ox got two wigs. Cat got three wigs. Dot got four wigs. Don got five wigs"? Or does it mean "Fox got the first wig. Ox got the second wig. Cat got the third wig. Dot got the fourth wig. Don got the fifth wig"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second interpretation is accurate. Here, one, two, three, four, and five are labels. Each animal got one wig. So, you can think of it as

> A big box sat upon a mat. Can Dog win the big box? Dog got the box! Fox got wig **number one**. Ox got wig **number two**. Cat got wig **number three**. Dot got wig **number four**. Don got wig **number five**. What a lot in a big box!

Comment: Can I think of "Cat got wig three" as "Cat got wig that has number three" ?

Comment: No because they wigs may not be literally numbered. I think your interpretation was the most accurate. I just wanted to give you another way to look at it.

Comment: Max// You are all right. I want to waiting longer. I am always thankful to the help of this site. By the way, can one be first and two be second?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I will postpone the approval for a moment according to your wishes. It is a very short sentence, but it is not interpreted well. why "wig one, wig two " instead of "first wig, second wig" in this sentence?

Comment: It seems to be a stylistic choice. I looked online and the sentences seem to be part of a fluency builder for learners or some kind of rhyming book for children. These kinds of short sentence are meant to be easy to read for practice.

Comment: As a native speaker, I consider this answer 100% accurate. It's an odd phrasing, yes, and it sounds like it's deliberately simplified for children or language learners. I'd guess for children, due to the exclamation marks.